# How to add space between two different emphasis tags

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm having a problem regarding spacing value between two different emphasis. The current output of the given xslt below is yet okay but there is no spacing between the two tags. Please help me with this as I dont know much about transformation. The detailed problem can be seen below.

Here is the input XML:

```
<caption>
    <content>Box</content>
      <number>1</number>
      <description>
        <em type="bold">Some text with scientic name: </em>
    <em type="bolditalic">fhadinistis</em>
      </description>
</caption>
```

The output is:

```
<cap>
    <text>Box</text>
    <num>1</num>
    <content>
        <b>Some text with scientic name:</b><b>
            <i>fhadinistis</i>
        </b>
    </content>
</cap>
```

Desired output should be:(notice that there is a space between the closing and opening bold tag)

```
<cap>
    <text>Box</text>
    <num>1</num>
    <content>
        <b>Some text with scientic name:</b> <b>
            <i>fhadinistis</i>
        </b>
    </content>
</cap>
```

My XSLT is:

```
<xsl:template match="em">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@type='bolditalic'">
            <b>
                <it>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </it>
            </b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='boldunderline'">
            <b>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </ul>
            </b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='italicunderline'">
            <it>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </ul>
            </it>
        </xsl:when>                 
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor are you using? And how does the rest of the stylesheet look? There is white space between the two `em` elements in the input sample you have posted so it should suffice to copy that through with other templates like the built-in ones.

Comment: The provided XSLT doesn't produce the provided output. Please, edit and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this at the start of the template:

```
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][self::em]">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Hi Dim, the code you have provided is awesome but still having the output of: Some <b>text</b> , <it>test</it> instead of; Some <b>text</b>, <it>test</it>

Comment: the sentence goes like this: Some text, test. So there is a comma.

Comment: @YuanRay: There is *no* comma anywhere in the output you have provided in the question as wanted.

Comment: I'm just assuming another sentence not the output. Anyway, in case there are commas, full stop, and any other usage, spaces are there. Can we eliminate that? Thanks Dim.

Comment: @YuanRay, Sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking. Please, think how to define this well in an easy to understand way. Then ask a new, separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you need a blank space, you could try using:

```
<xsl:text>#x20;</xsl:text>
```

even

```
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
```

should do the trick but it's easy to miss blank spaces in code, better to use the #x20; for visibility.

You could put it after the xsl:choose close tag. So even if xsl:choose = nothing and you get multiple black spaces, HTML will only display 1 (by default)

Implement it as:

```
<xsl:template match="em">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@type='bolditalic'">
            <b>
                <it>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </it>
            </b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='boldunderline'">
            <b>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </ul>
            </b>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='italicunderline'">
            <it>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </ul>
            </it>
        </xsl:when>                 
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:text>#x20;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: </xsl:choose>
 <xsl:text>#x20;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template> I have no idea if it is going to work for you, just an idea! (Sorry don't know how to comment 'code')

Comment: But it create spaces for all emphasis. Eg: Some <b>text</b> , <it>test</it> instead of; Some <b>text</b>, <it>test</it>

Comment: You might need to move it to where you want it. Should it go after the line: <xsl:when test="@type='bolditalic'"> ?